# Add extra column of data when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE

Tags: mysql

I'm using the following LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE query to read data from a file and insert it into a table.  Everything works great as is.  However I need to modify the query to support one additional requirement.

I need to add an extra column to the data.  Essentially my raw data does not include a date field and I need to include a column where I can add the date the data was imported.  The file will be automatically imported once a day and I need to add that date to the data.

Is there a way to add a column of data when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE?  I can easily capture today's date, but I don't know how to add it to the query below.

```
$insert_query = LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/mydata.csv' 
INSERT INTO TABLE myTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4);

$db->setQuery($insert_query);
$res = $db->query();
```

Any suggestions will be greatly appreciated!!!  Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can add a `SET` clause to the end of the query, e.g.

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE 'C:/mydata.csv' 
INSERT INTO TABLE myTable
FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' 
OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"' 
LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n' 
IGNORE 1 LINES 
(Column1,Column2,Column3,Column4)
SET datetime = NOW();
```

Comment: Either answer works, but this one works best for me.  I'm always super impressed by the quality of the answers in Stackoverflow.  Thanks!

Comment: Is there any way to modify data present in csv file? e.g. user can upload csv with country like `INDIA` but in database I need to store its id like `91`

Comment: @RNKushwaha I think you can do this by including a variable in the column list, like `...,Column4,@Country` and then doing something with that variable in your SET clause, like `SET datetime = NOW(), Column5 = CASE @Country WHEN 'INDIA' THEN 91 END CASE`

Answer (score 6):

Rather than add this field to the query, it would be easier to add it to the table:

```
ALTER TABLE myTable
    ADD COLUMN datetime_entered TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
```

Any insertion will then automatically have a timestamp of when the record was entered.