# CakePHP: Add user input to record alongside data read from an infile

Tags: php, mysql, cakephp

I have a CakePHP application that stores "mission" data. Every time a new mission is created, a static input file is read and 592 new records are inserted into the 'missions' table. Basically, a single column is populated with permanent data. I've got that working just fine. The Model code looks like this:

```
public function importCSV($csv_name) { 
    $sql = "LOAD DATA INFILE '{$csv_name}' INTO TABLE missions
            LINES TERMINATED BY '\r'
            (or_identity)";

    $this->query($sql);
}
```

And here is the controller code:

```
public function add() {
    if($this->request->is('post')) {
        $this->Requirement->create();
        $csv_name = /path/to/csv/file
        if($this->Requirement->save($this->request->data)) {
            $this->Requirement->importCSV($csv_name);
            $this->Session->setFlash(__('The new mission has been created.'));
            return $this->redirect(array('action' => 'index'));
        } else {
            $this->Session->SetFlash(__('Unable to create mission.'));
        }
    }
}
```

...and user input from the View:

```
echo $this->Form->input('mission_id', array('type' => 'textbox', 'label' => 'Mission ID (Ex: OA-5)'));
```

When a user creates a new mission, they are required to enter a Mission ID, which will be something like "OA-5." This Mission ID is in its own column in the 'missions' table. What I can't figure out how to do is make sure that Mission ID is inserted along with the 592 new records. It needs to be there to form a concatenated key. How can I modify my methods to allow this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just insert it in the same SQL call. You can add additional fields to the query. See [Add extra column of data when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868443/add-extra-column-of-data-when-using-load-data-local-infile) for how to do it. For additional info [check the manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/load-data.html).

Taken from the manual:

```
LOAD DATA [LOW_PRIORITY | CONCURRENT] [LOCAL] INFILE 'file_name'
    [REPLACE | IGNORE]
    INTO TABLE tbl_name
    [PARTITION (partition_name,...)]
    [CHARACTER SET charset_name]
    [{FIELDS | COLUMNS}
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
        [[OPTIONALLY] ENCLOSED BY 'char']
        [ESCAPED BY 'char']
    ]
    [LINES
        [STARTING BY 'string']
        [TERMINATED BY 'string']
    ]
    [IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]
    [(col_name_or_user_var,...)]
    [SET col_name = expr,...]
```

Comment: Awesome solution. The only problem I have now is that it looks like Cake is doing an initial insert of the mission_id, which means I end up with 593 rows instead of 592. The first row only contains the mission_id, and all subsequent rows have the mission_id and the data from the infile. How can I prevent the first insertion?

Comment: Remove that first line from the file or please *read the documentation* of the SQL function. By more than just a quick look I can see that it supports `[IGNORE number {LINES | ROWS}]`. So just alter the query to ignore that line.

Comment: The IGNORE clause refers to ignoring the first line of the infile. I don't want to do that. I want to keep CakePHP from first INSERTING the mission_id on its own and THEN reading the infile and setting mission_id to what the user provided.

Comment: I'm pretty sure this happens because the first line contains not all the data but just a CSV "header".

Comment: Adding the IGNORE clause just makes it ignore the first line of data in the infile. Even with it there, cake still does an insert of the mission_id BEFORE it starts reading the infile. I just need to suppress that first insert somehow.

Comment: Well, you're obviously doing a save() before, so you get that "empty" record from this `if($this->Requirement->save($this->request->data)) {`.