# Concatenate my php variable to csv data when importing LOAD DATA INFILE

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, load-data-infile, mysqlimport

I need to import some csv files to mysql.

I recently found about the LOAD DATA INFILE, I checked the manual, as far as I understand, to imports each line of .csv file to the database.

I was wondering if there's an option to concatenate an extra value to what the csv file contains.

For example: my table has 3 columns.

MYTABLE(#name,#email,company_adrs);

The csv file has data for "name,email" only, and I have the address in a php variable.

With a normal loop, I would achieve this as follows:

```
//open file
while (/* not end of file, read eachline*/)
{
  $current_line_of_csv_file; // contains: "John,john@john.com" without the 3rd column
  $myAddrsVar= mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['adrs']); //"44 company st" 
  $insert = $db->query("INSERT MYTABLE (name,email,company_adrs) VALUES ( $current_line_of_csv_file,'".$myAddrsVar."')");

}
```

With this method I have to loop through each line the csv and do a query in each iteration.

I was wondering if LOAD DATA INFILE has a method to concatenate my data to the csv file? if so, how can I achieve it?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do each record in the CSV have the same company address?

Comment: @zedfoxus, yes, they all have the same company, but the address is a user input that comes from a form, that's why it's stored in a php variable

Comment: How many rows do you have in CSV?

Comment: ~100 per file, but we will have multiple files every couple of days. it's a page that allows a non-techy-person to import data to my database by only entering the company name once in a form, select the file and the script imports the data. I though about concatenating ",$myAddrsVar" at the end of each line of the csv file, but this will be the same as looping through the file in the example I gave. The only difference is that we insert in the file instead of inserting into the database.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given your situation, I would recommend using PHP all-in-all and insert data into MySQL that way.

https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-getcsv.php can help you parse CSV into an array. Add to the array the address. Now, you'd have the dataset in an array.

Use prepared statements like shown here https://websitebeaver.com/prepared-statements-in-php-mysqli-to-prevent-sql-injection and insert data one after the other.

Use transactions so that all data is inserted or no data is insert. See [How to start and end transaction in mysqli?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12091971/how-to-start-and-end-transaction-in-mysqli).

I'd avoid using LOAD DATA INLINE because the volume of data is not that big. If you really want to use it and add another column, you can use `SET` statement. There's an example of that here: [Add extra column of data when using LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22868443/add-extra-column-of-data-when-using-load-data-local-infile)

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions! I gave the 1st option a try, and it worked. But in the end I went with the LOAD DATA INLINE  option.
Thanks a lot, I didn't know about the set option.
Btw, the transactions things seems so useful, thanks for the tip.